# How to sync 2 different mongodb database collections

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have 2 different mongodb databases hosted on different platform as per the development requirements.Our davelopment database is hosted on AWS EC2 instance and production is hosted on Atlas.Here both development and production databases have products collection.

I want to sync this product collection like whenever there is change in production database collection my development should get updated.

I know I can export  the data from production using mongodump and import in development db but it requires manual efforts can I make it in any other way.

Comment: You could monitor the production database's [change stream](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) and update your development database.

Comment: Here the thing is in development db I have few more fields in documents as compared to production db so how can I added those field along with it.

Comment: Possibly you could [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) the new production values into your development documents, or some other update operation that preserves the fields you want.